# Who translated the book “The Lady With a Little Dog” used in movie “The Reader”?

Tags: reference, the-reader

I found the Anton Chekov story "The Lady With the Dog", which is translated by Constance Garnett. It does not match with the story read by Michael in the movie "The Reader". Can anyone tell me who translated the book read in the movie?

Comment: There are several translations.  Ivy Litvinov, Avrahm Yarmolinsky. Is there a close up image of the book jacket from the film that you can post? Or a screen shot of the book being read...

Comment: Michael starts reading this way, "The talk was that a new face had appeared on the promenade, a lady with a little dog." I could not find a book which starts this way.

Comment: I do know the title translates variously as: The Lady with the Dog, The Lady with the Little Dog, The Lady with the Toy Dog. So I'd check translations of The Lady With the Little Dog.

Comment: No, the title is "The Lady with a Little Dog".

Comment: I haven't seen that version of the title yet. Who translated it?

Comment: That was my question actually.

Comment: http://www.eldritchpress.org/ac/lapdog.html This starts with the "promenade"